# Put state from React context provider in const

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm receiving the states from my App provider but i need that state in a const or in my child component state. But i can't find a way to do it.

For example I want something like this:

```
const admin =  <MyContext.Consumer>{() => 
                this.setState({username: (context => 
                context.state.name)})}
               </MyContext.Consumer>;
```

Or:

```
const admin = <MyContext.Consumer>{(context) => context.state.name}</MyContext.Consumer>
```

admin would contain the value of the state name.

I know my approach won't work, but what approach should i take to make something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<MyContext.Consumer>` can only be used in render, and the value it provides can only be accessed in the child function you pass to it. If you need access to it other lifecycle hooks, such as to call setState with it, there are a couple options. If you're using React 16.6 (the latest version as i write this), you can use a [static contextType](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/23/react-v-16-6.html#static-contexttype) (note that it's contextType singular, not contextTypes plural)

```
export class MyComponent extends Component {
  static contextType = MyContext;

  componentDidMount() {
    // value is available on this.context, so you can do things like:
    this.setState({ username: this.context.state.name });
  }
}
```

Prior to React 16.6, you can wrap your component in another component, and then interact with the value through props on the main component:

```
export const MyComponent = props => (
  <MyContext.Consumer>
    {context => <InnerComponent someExtraProp={context} {...props} />}
  </MyContext.Consumer>
);

class InnerComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      username: this.props.someExtraProp.state.name,
    });
  }
}
```